# FirebaseUI TableViewController Segue

Tags: firebase

I am trying to use FirebaseUI to populate three `UITableViewControllers` with data in Xcode 7. I would like for the user to be able to press a cell on the first Controller and then be brought to a list of data on the second view controller based on what they pressed on the first Controller. I would also like this to be the case between the second and third Controllers. I've figured out how to pull in the data, but I have no idea how to segue between the Controllers. Thank you for your help!

Here is my old code that I was using with arrays that had nothing to do with Firebase.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController

    var SecondTableArrayTwo : SecondTable

    SecondTableArrayTwo = SecondArray[indexPath.row]

    DestViewController.SecondArray = SecondTableArrayTwo.SecondTitle
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: @DavidEast I have this old code that worked back when I was using arrays without Firebase. I have no idea how to make it work with Firebase though. I'll put it in my question.

Comment: Is the question 'How do I segue between two controllers' which is a swift question or is the question 'how to I load data into a controller from firebase'?

Comment: @Jay the question is 'How do I segue between two controllers'. But the controllers contain Firebase data which I already know how to do.

Comment: Typically you would implement prepareForSegue followed by performSegue. However, if you've set it up in IB (from a cell to a segue for example) the heavy lifting is done for you. There's a ton of tutorials on segue'ing on the internet and your use may vary a bit. Try searching for 'Segue between Swift View Controllers'